# What's recommended solution for search engine in TYPO3 CMS v8

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-extensions

I've a database with approximately 50k records and I've just migrated it to TYPO3 v8. I'm looking for some efficient search extension. What would you suggest?

Some time ago I've been using ke_search extension, but I've just tested it and it does not work at TYPO3 v8, it's not compatible. I need flexible solution, where I can easly create new filtering options in search formular. Due to this I don't consider native search extension indexed_search. I've heared about Apache Solr, but yet didn't have an occasion to integrate it for the needs of TYPO3 CMS. What are the possibilities?

Comment: Just to note: A TYPO3 V8 compatible version of ke_search will come soon. See commits in ke_search repository on GitHub https://github.com/teaminmedias-pluswerk/ke_search/commits/master

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, Solr are the only option if ke_search doesn't work.

Use this extension - https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/solr - the manual is detailed and should help you with the settings.